# Why do we need regression in Barra factor model?

Tags: factor-models

I am trying to understand Barra factor model, so bear with me.

I will describe my current understanding because maybe I am missing something.

We have k factors and some defined formulas to compute exposure of stock i to factor k. Let us call this exposure e_ik.

We also know actual return for each stock r_i.

Here is the step that I do not really understand.

To compute factor return for factor k (f_k) we try to select f_k as to minimize
sum ( ri - sum_k(f_k*e_ik) )^2, essentially trying to minimize sum of residual returns. Right? So, we have an optimization problem with k variables (different factor returns)

My question is do we really need this optimization step? Would it not be more intuitive if we just defined f_k= sum_i(e_ik * r_i)? So f_k would represent return of portfolio where each weight in stock is proportional to e_ik. Am I missing something or misunderstanding?

Comment: The terminology one uses when talking about the barra model is very important because there are "exposures" that go into creating an overall  factor exposure so the use of the term exposure can be ambiguous. I vaguely remember this paper being the clearest as far as explaining the gory details behind the barra model. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2330027 so if you can get access to it, it will hopefully clear things up for you. Any "sales" presentation from Barra or MSCI is probably not going to be helpful because those will gloss over the gory details.